# opening file with fopen,c\ubuntu

Tags: c, eclipse, ubuntu, fopen

Im trying to open file with fopen,and to read\write for "huffman tree".
After i've finished reading from the text, I tried to write in another file a "dictionary" that say what is the code for every letter.
I've got an eror that i havnt find something similar except that the reason is old version of eclipse, but it wasn't the problam.
Im programing in c with eclipse in ubuntu.

the main is look like:

```
int main(){
    FILE *fsrc;
    node *root;
    if( (fsrc  = fopen( "src.txt", "r" )) == NULL ){ //
        printf( "The file 'src.txt' was not opened\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        printf( "The file 'src.txt' was opened\n" );
    }
    root = getBinTree(fsrc);
    printTree(&(*root));
    huffman(root); 
    return 0;
}
```

this is the function that writing to to target text

```
void printhtree(node *n,FILE *trg){
       char *str = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
       node *ptr=n;
       while (!(ptr->m_hls && ptr->m_hrs)){
           while(ptr->m_hls){
               n=ptr;
               ptr = ptr->m_hls;
               str = realloc(1,sizeof(char)*(strlength(str)+1));
               *(str+strlength(str)-1)='0';
           }//while
           if(!(ptr->m_hrs)){
               printf("%s-%c ",str,ptr->m_ch);
               n->m_hls = NULL;
               return;
           }//if
           while(ptr->m_hrs){
               n=ptr;
               ptr = ptr->m_hrs;
               str = realloc(1,sizeof(char)*(strlength(str)+1));
               *(str+strlength(str)-1)='1';
           }//while
       }//while
       if (!(ptr->m_ch)){
           fputc(ptr->m_ch,trg);
           fputc(' ',trg);
           fputs(str,trg);

           n->m_hls = NULL;
           return;
       }//if
   }//printhtree
```

and this is the function that activate |pringhtree" function:

```
  ‪void drawTree(node *n,FILE *trg‬‬){
        while(!(n))
           printhtree(n,trg);
   }
```

the error is on the first line of draw tree : 
"void drawTree(node *n,FILE *trg‬‬)"
and it says: 
"multiple markers at this line
bad character sequence encountered
stray '\252' in program, and the same line with the numbers 254,342,200.

there is the same error also where i wrote the names of all the function in the beginning of the program.

thank you very much

Comment: You copied the code from somewhere that encoded it as UTF8 (possibly a web page), and the compiler complains about these characters since they are not allowed in C code (at least for the compiler and C version you are using).

Comment: the code wasn't copied from the web, i wrote it by myself.
it was  "abbc".
what can i do to fix it?

Comment: So you were right, the problam was that i copied my code from txt file and there were a lot of unvisible signs that cause a lot of problam.
thank youu very much :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an important issue in your code

```
str = realloc(1,sizeof(char)*(strlength(str)+1));
```

For many reasons

1. The syntax is wrong, as it is you are `realloc()`ing the address `0x01`.
2. You should not immediately overwrite the pointer, because if an error occurs then you will be unable to recover, a good usage of `realloc()` would be like

   ```
   void *tmp = realloc(str, 1 + strlength(str));
   if (tmp != NULL)
       str = tmp;
   ```
3. This is not wrong, but it makes your code unnecessarily ugly, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.
4. Presumably `strlength()` emulates `strlen()`, so you don't want to compute the length twice, store it and use the value.
5. You allocate space the first time with `malloc()` but you drop that pointer completely because of the misuse of `realloc()` in your code, moreover you don't really need to allocate space except before writing to the pointed data, so you can replace your `realloc()` with `malloc()` and remove the `calloc()`, which by the way unnecessarily initialized all the values to `0`, you don't need that.
6. You only initialize the last value of `str` which is set to `'\0'`, but the rest of the data remains uninitialized because the function that would actually be allocating memory would be `realloc()` if it were used correctly, specially since `calloc()` is allocating a single byte.